# pyodbc to remote sqlite database not working but no errors thrown

Tags: python, sqlite, raspberry-pi, odbc, debian-based

I have a Raspberry Pi running [OSMC](https://osmc.tv/), a media-optimized version of Debian. This Pi holds an SQLITE database that I would like to access using Python from my Windows 7 PC. Both computers are on the same home network.

As recommended by this [similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31164610/connect-to-sqlite3-server-using-pyodbc-python), I obtained an [SQLITE ODBC driver](http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/).

I wrote the following code to query the database. The code is not throwing any exceptions, but neither is it returning any data. What I am doing wrong?

```
import pyodbc

def connectToDB():
    serverIP = '192.168.0.110' #raspberry pi on home network
    databaseName = 'pigarage.db'
    sql = 'DRIVER={SQLite3 ODBC Driver};SERVER=%s;DATABASE=%s;Trusted_connection=yes' % (serverIP, databaseName)
    conn = pyodbc.connect(sql)
    return conn

def runQuery(conn, sql):
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql)
    result = list( cursor.fetchall() ) # list of tuples
    cursor.close()
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    conn = connectToDB()
    print conn
    sql = 'select distinct state from GarageDoorState'
    print runQuery(conn, sql)
    conn.close()
    print 'completed successfully'
```

OUTPUT:

```
<pyodbc.Connection object at 0x035434E8>
[]
completed successfully
```

I noticed the ODBC connection did not require any kind of port (not sure SQLite needs this, as it is not a server DB?), or a user / pwd, etc. I think I am just confused about the process, and that my setup is just wrong. But then I am puzzled why no errors from the code?

[image: ODBC setup]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An SQLite database is a file, and is accessed as a file.

When you give the database name `pigarage.db` to the driver, it will open (or create) a file with that name. (Without a directory name, it will use whatever happens to be the current directory.)

To access a database on another machine, you need to use a network file system (see [Samba](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/samba)), and ensure that it is [correctly configured](http://www.sqlite.org/howtocorrupt.html#_filesystems_with_broken_or_missing_lock_implementations).

Comment: Thanks, that did it. I installed a samba server on my Raspberry Pi and then used the following connection string to access it: `sql = "DRIVER=SQLite3 ODBC Driver;Database=r'\\192.168.0.114\pi\pigarage.db;"`